# VS-Code reports NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system on Linux RHEL7

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I upgraded vscode to 1.81 and now it will not discover python tests. The full text of the error is this. I don't even know where to begin looking, since this worked this morning with a previous version of vscode.

```
2023-08-31 17:23:08.994 [error] Error while trying to run pytest discovery, 
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise SystemExit(pytest.console_main())
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 188, in console_main
    code = main()
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 166, in main
    config=config
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 315, in pytest_cmdline_main
    return wrap_session(config, _main)
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 304, in wrap_session
    session=session, exitstatus=session.exitstatus
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 55, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/terminal.py", line 792, in pytest_sessionfinish
    outcome.get_result()
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/cacheprovider.py", line 385, in pytest_sessionfinish
    saved_lastfailed = config.cache.get("cache/lastfailed", {})
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/cacheprovider.py", line 158, in get
    path = self._getvaluepath(key)
  File "/ascldap/users/mhamilt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/cacheprovider.py", line 144, in _getvaluepath
    return self._cachedir.joinpath(self._CACHE_PREFIX_VALUES, Path(key))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 1004, in __new__
    % (cls.__name__,))
NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system
```

Comment: I'd start from `ctrl shift p` -> configure tests and reconfigure the test suite (choose pytest as framework, point to the correct folder again and so on), then I'd choose interpreter for the workspace to make sure VS Code is using the correct one. Then make sure everything was correctly applied, by inspecting settings.json in .vscode folder.